# What problems could disabling Java bytecode verification cause?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, verification, jvm-bytecode

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/755012/200783) says that verification is used to ensure that Java bytecode "follows Java language rules for safety".

If this verification were not performed, unsafe bytecode would be allowed to run. What problems could this cause?

Are there any situations in which disabling bytecode verification would be acceptable?

Comment: Crashing, data corruption, the feel of being dirty, etc. You should ask the other way round: what advantage should disabling verification have?

Comment: [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321205/jvm-crash-problematic-frame-canonicalizerdo-if) of what may happen when you turn off the verification.

Answer (score 2):

Bytecode verification ensures that the code can't do stuff like reinterpret an int as a pointer and do arbitrary memory accesses. This is most useful if you are trying to run untrusted code within the Java sandbox.

If you completely trust all the code you are running, it is less useful, since it would just catch accidental bugs in that case. It's also possible that the verification information gets fed into the optimizer - I'm not sure about this, but the optimizer essentially has to verify the code anyway in order to do any useful static analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended not to use "-Xverify:none" options  in production environment as it disables byte code verification and lead to random crashes. Please check detailed blog [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/buck/entry/never_disable_bytecode_verification_in)